# Parsing a structured text using boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

Once more, I would like to ask for your help. Using the boost spirit library, I would like to parse the syntax below into the struct "unitConstruct". So far my parser fails and is not able to parse correctly this syntax. Your help will be highly appreciated. Please, find a snapshot of my code below.

This syntax will follow this format as is based on a standard. I would like to store **UNIT** in key(as shown in the **struct unitConstruct**), and store **TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT** in identifier, and finally I would like to store the tokens in the vector (**variablereferences**). This pattern is required to uniquely retrieve this information later in my code.

```
// Syntax to be parsed
UNIT TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT
{
trans1_primary_value_unit:
    trans1_primary_value,
    trans1_scale_out_lower_value,
    trans1_scale_out_upper_value,
    func1_AI_pv_upper_range_value,
    func1_AI_pv_lower_range_value,
    func1_AI_simulate_value
}

//structure  to store the syntax above 
struct unitConstruct
{
    std::string key;
    std::string identifier;
    std::vector<std::string> variablereferences;
};


// code snapshot 
typedef std::vector<unitConstruct> eddlParsedData
template <typename Iterator>
struct skipper : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
    skipper() : skipper::base_type(start)
    {
        start = ascii::blank;
    }
private:
    qi::rule<Iterator> start, comment;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct eddlparser : qi::grammar<Iterator, eddlParsedData(), skipper<Iterator> >
{
    eddlparser() : eddlparser::base_type(start)
    {
        unitkey = qi::string("UNIT");
        text = +qi::graph;
        unit = unitkey >> text >> qi::eol
                       >> '{' >> qi::eol
                       >> +text >> qi::eol
                       >> '}' ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(unit);
        start = (unit) % *qi::eol;
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), skipper<Iterator> > uni, unitkey, text;
    qi::rule<Iterator, unitConstruct(), skipper<Iterator> > unit;


// adapt unitConstruct as a Fusion sequence
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    unitConstruct,
    (std::string, key)
    (std::string, identifier)
    (std::vector<std::string>, variablereferences)
)
```

Comment: When you parse this example, do you expect `key` to be `"TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT"`, `identifier` to be `"trans1_primary_value_unit"`, and `variablereferences` contain the 6 tokens after the colon, that are separated by commas? I'm just trying to make sure that I understand what the grammar should be, it would be handy if you could describe it outside the code, just to make it clear.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I would like **key** to be **"UNIT"**; **identifier** to be **"TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT"** and **variablereferences** to contain the 6 tokens. Regarding the commas and colon, i would like to strip all the commas and colons from the tokens.

Comment: OK. Where should `trans1_primary_value_unit` go? Also, why do you even need the `key` there? Is it possible that `unitConstruct` type will also represent something else?

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40496516/edit) your question, and elaborate a little bit more on the data you are trying to parse? What is the meaning if the individual tokens there? Also, is it really necessary to require newlines to be there? The way it seems to me is that they could easily be treated as white-space, and therefore skipped, and it would not be ambiguous.

Comment: The **trans1_primary_value_unit** will always be the first element in the vector as the other 5 tokens depend on its value. **"unitstruct"** is just to help me store multiple number of the "UNIT" keyword and its corresponding data. I have several other keywords in my data which i also store in different structs. This explains why i would like to parse and retrieve all information of the **UNIT**  keyword based on the **unitConstruct** struct

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have an additional member to store the value of `trans1_primary_value_unit`, rather than keeping it as a first element of the vector? It will actually make it easier to define the grammar then. Oh, and sorry to nitpick, but there are 6 tokens after the colon, not 5 ;) No biggie tho.

Comment: OK, yes i think it will also be ok to have for example a string data type as an additional member for **trans1_primary_value_unit**. You could please suggest with this idea.

Comment: Good. Few more questions, again update your question with the details I ask for. 1) Should the keyword `UNIT` be case sensitive? 2) What symbols can a unit test identifier contain? 3) What should we call the new member (as in what does `trans1_primary_value_unit` represent? unit test function?) 4) What symbols can the as yet unnamed token and the dependencies contain?

Comment: 1) yes, the keyword UNIT is case-sensitive                                                                                          2)  identifier will always be a string as it refers to the name of this particular UNIT keyword.  3) good question :), The **trans1_primary_value_unit** contains a unit code, which could be any data type...perhaps for now...we could restrict the data types to the primitive ones (integer, string, float etc) 4) The other 5 tokens depend on the type of the first(tratrans1_primary_value_unit) token

Comment: Ok, but why I'm asking #2 and #4 is that `qi::graph` will match any non-whitespace characters. It's fairly obvious that a comma shouldn't be matched there, as it's used as a separator. Same would got for `{` and `}`. There may be other symbols that don't make sense here.

Comment: OK...perhaps that is why my parser was not working properly...what will be your suggestion?

Comment: From what you have in the example, #4 might be lower and upper case letters, digits and underscore. #2 would be similar, perhaps with a restriction to upper case only? At the least this will be a good starting point, you can always extend it.

Comment: yes, i agree with you

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear enough. I'll put together an answer. Hope you can wait till tomorrow, I'm getting a bit sleepy now :)

Comment: yes...i will wait...i appreciate your efforts so far

Comment: one last point, the start rule should be same as in my example, as the same start rule is being used for other keywords as well

Comment: @DanMašek please did you manage to find a solution to the problem?

Comment: I added a little explanation on parsing multiple definitions in sequence.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks very much...to be very honest your solution looks very professional...

Comment: @kofi you should now be able to give Dan's excellent answer a well-deserved upvote.

Comment: @jv_ yes...how can i do an upvote?...perhpas i have to read about it...Dan deserves it.

Comment: @kofi at the start of the answer there is a number (currently `1`) and two arrows, you need to press the one that goes up. You couldn't before, but now that your rep is over 15 I think you can.

Comment: @jv_ many thanks...i just did...i really wanted to go as high as i could...but my maximum was upvote of 2

Comment: @kofi you can only upvote once in a question/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your example and the details we discussed in comments. You want to parse a *definition* that looks as follows.

```
UNIT TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT
{
trans1_primary_value_unit:
    trans1_primary_value,
    trans1_scale_out_lower_value,
    trans1_scale_out_upper_value,
    func1_AI_pv_upper_range_value,
    func1_AI_pv_lower_range_value,
    func1_AI_simulate_value
}
```

- `UNIT` specifies definition *type*. Only upper case is allowed, and we desire to only use predefined keywords (just "UNIT" at this point).
- `TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT` specifies definition *name*. It may contain upper case letters, digits or an underscore. The first symbol may not be a digit.
- *Identifiers* may consist of lower and upper case letters, digits or underscores. The first symbol may not be a digit.
- `trans1_primary_value_unit` specifies a single *dependent*. It is an *identifier*.
- `trans1_primary_value`, ... `func1_AI_simulate_value` specify *dependencies*. Each *dependency* is an identifier. Multiple dependencies are separated by commas.

Based on this information, we need a grammar that looks as follows (in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)).

```
type = 'UNIT'
name = ( upper | "_" ), { upper | digit | "_" }
identifier = ( upper | lower | "_" ), { upper | lower | digit | "_" }
dependent = identifier
dependency = identifier
dependencies = dependency, { ",", dependency }
definition = type, name, "{", dependent, ":", dependencies, "}"
```

We can use phrase parsing ignoring spaces, tabs, newlines and returns, since we don't require them to parse this correctly.

## Source Code

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2965fb127f9f523)</kbd>

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
// ======================================================================
std::string TEST_INPUT = R"(UNIT TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT
{
trans1_primary_value_unit:
    trans1_primary_value,
    trans1_scale_out_lower_value,
    trans1_scale_out_upper_value,
    func1_AI_pv_upper_range_value,
    func1_AI_pv_lower_range_value,
    func1_AI_simulate_value
}
)";
// ======================================================================
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
// ======================================================================
struct definition
{
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    std::string dependent;
    std::vector<std::string> dependencies;
};
// ======================================================================
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    definition,
    (std::string, type)
    (std::string, name)
    (std::string, dependent)
    (std::vector<std::string>, dependencies)
)
// ======================================================================
template <typename Iterator>
struct skipper
    : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
    skipper()
        : skipper::base_type(start)
    {
        start %= ascii::space;
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};
// ======================================================================
template <typename Iterator>
struct def_parser
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, definition(), skipper<Iterator> >
{
    def_parser()
        : def_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        def_type %= qi::string("UNIT");

        def_name %= (ascii::upper | ascii::char_('_'))
            >> *(ascii::upper | ascii::digit | ascii::char_('_'));

        identifier %= (ascii::upper | ascii::lower | ascii::char_('_'))
            >> *(ascii::upper | ascii::lower | ascii::digit | ascii::char_('_'));
        def_dependent %= identifier;
        def_dependency %= identifier;
        def_dependencies %= def_dependency % qi::lit(",");

        start %= def_type
            >> def_name
            >> qi::lit("{")
            >> def_dependent
            >> qi::lit(":")
            >> def_dependencies
            >> qi::lit("}")
            ;

        init_debug();
    }

    void init_debug()
    {
        def_type.name("def_type");
        def_name.name("def_name");
        identifier.name("identifier");
        def_dependent.name("def_dependent");
        def_dependency.name("def_dependency");
        def_dependencies.name("def_dependencies");
        start.name("start");

        qi::debug(def_type);
        qi::debug(def_name);
        qi::debug(identifier);
        qi::debug(def_dependent);
        qi::debug(def_dependency);
        qi::debug(def_dependencies);
        qi::debug(start);
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_type;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_name;    
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> identifier;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_dependent;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_dependency;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), skipper<Iterator>> def_dependencies;

    qi::rule<Iterator, definition(), skipper<Iterator>> start;
};
// ======================================================================
int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;

    def_parser<iterator_type> g;
    skipper<iterator_type> s;

    definition d;

    iterator_type iter = TEST_INPUT.begin();
    iterator_type end = TEST_INPUT.end();

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, g, s, d);

    if (r) {
        std::cout << "Bytes left = " << std::distance(iter, end) << " -> "
            << ((iter == end) ? "SUCCEEDED" : "FAILED") << "\n";
        std::cout << "Type = " << d.type << "\n";
        std::cout << "Name = " << d.name << "\n";
        std::cout << "Dependent = " << d.dependent << "\n";        
        for (auto const& ref : d.dependencies) {
            std::cout << "Dependency = " << ref << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "FAILED COMPLETELY\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
// ======================================================================
```

### Debug Output

```
<start>
  <try>UNIT TB_SENSOR_PRIMA</try>
  <def_type>
    <try>UNIT TB_SENSOR_PRIMA</try>
    <success> TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_V</success>
    <attributes>[[U, N, I, T]]</attributes>
  </def_type>
  <def_name>
    <try> TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_V</try>
    <success>{\ntrans1_primary_val</success>
    <attributes>[[T, B, _, S, E, N, S, O, R, _, P, R, I, M, A, R, Y, _, V, A, L, U, E, _, U, N, I, T]]</attributes>
  </def_name>
  <def_dependent>
    <try>\ntrans1_primary_valu</try>
    <identifier>
      <try>\ntrans1_primary_valu</try>
      <success>:\n    trans1_primary</success>
      <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e, _, u, n, i, t]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <success>:\n    trans1_primary</success>
    <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e, _, u, n, i, t]]</attributes>
  </def_dependent>
  <def_dependencies>
    <try>\n    trans1_primary_</try>
    <def_dependency>
      <try>\n    trans1_primary_</try>
      <identifier>
        <try>\n    trans1_primary_</try>
        <success>,\n    trans1_scale_o</success>
        <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
      </identifier>
      <success>,\n    trans1_scale_o</success>
      <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
    </def_dependency>
    <def_dependency>
      <try>\n    trans1_scale_ou</try>
      <identifier>
        <try>\n    trans1_scale_ou</try>
        <success>,\n    trans1_scale_o</success>
        <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
      </identifier>
      <success>,\n    trans1_scale_o</success>
      <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
    </def_dependency>
    <def_dependency>
      <try>\n    trans1_scale_ou</try>
      <identifier>
        <try>\n    trans1_scale_ou</try>
        <success>,\n    func1_AI_pv_up</success>
        <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
      </identifier>
      <success>,\n    func1_AI_pv_up</success>
      <attributes>[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
    </def_dependency>
    <def_dependency>
      <try>\n    func1_AI_pv_upp</try>
      <identifier>
        <try>\n    func1_AI_pv_upp</try>
        <success>,\n    func1_AI_pv_lo</success>
        <attributes>[[f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
      </identifier>
      <success>,\n    func1_AI_pv_lo</success>
      <attributes>[[f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
    </def_dependency>
    <def_dependency>
      <try>\n    func1_AI_pv_low</try>
      <identifier>
        <try>\n    func1_AI_pv_low</try>
        <success>,\n    func1_AI_simul</success>
        <attributes>[[f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
      </identifier>
      <success>,\n    func1_AI_simul</success>
      <attributes>[[f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
    </def_dependency>
    <def_dependency>
      <try>\n    func1_AI_simula</try>
      <identifier>
        <try>\n    func1_AI_simula</try>
        <success>}\n</success>
        <attributes>[[f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, s, i, m, u, l, a, t, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
      </identifier>
      <success>}\n</success>
      <attributes>[[f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, s, i, m, u, l, a, t, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
    </def_dependency>
    <success>}\n</success>
    <attributes>[[[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e], [t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e], [t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e], [f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e], [f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e], [f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, s, i, m, u, l, a, t, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]]</attributes>
  </def_dependencies>
  <success>\n</success>
  <attributes>[[[U, N, I, T], [T, B, _, S, E, N, S, O, R, _, P, R, I, M, A, R, Y, _, V, A, L, U, E, _, U, N, I, T], [t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e, _, u, n, i, t], [[t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, p, r, i, m, a, r, y, _, v, a, l, u, e], [t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e], [t, r, a, n, s, 1, _, s, c, a, l, e, _, o, u, t, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, v, a, l, u, e], [f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, u, p, p, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e], [f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, p, v, _, l, o, w, e, r, _, r, a, n, g, e, _, v, a, l, u, e], [f, u, n, c, 1, _, A, I, _, s, i, m, u, l, a, t, e, _, v, a, l, u, e]]]]</attributes>
</start>
```

### Console Output

```
Bytes left = 0 -> SUCCEEDED
Type = UNIT
Name = TB_SENSOR_PRIMARY_VALUE_UNIT
Dependent = trans1_primary_value_unit
Dependency = trans1_primary_value
Dependency = trans1_scale_out_lower_value
Dependency = trans1_scale_out_upper_value
Dependency = func1_AI_pv_upper_range_value
Dependency = func1_AI_pv_lower_range_value
Dependency = func1_AI_simulate_value
```

## Parsing Multiple Definitions

We already have a grammar for a single definition. To parse multiple definitions, we just reuse this.

Let's make some minor modifications to the code:

- `std::vector<definition> d;`
- `bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, +g, s, d);`

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/837f81540581dc54)</kbd>

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think the `'_'` in `def_name` and `identifier` should be `char_('_')` (or maybe put everything inside a `qi::raw[]`).

Comment: @jv_ Good point, `'_'` is a `lit` and therefore according to the documentaiton it doesn't synthesize an attribute. And right you are, they don't, somehow I completely missed them disappearing. Thanks.